# "Non-static method 'getActivity()' cannot be referenced from a static context" in recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-actionmode

I made custom gallery using fragment and recyclerview. I want to make multiple selection within it, to appear Actionbar with menu when I select pictures.
So I made ActionMode in my adapter and tried to start action mode when the image were long clicked. But I can't bring the activity of my gallery fragment... with the error "Non-static method 'getActivity()' cannot be referenced from a static context".

Furthermore, I selected only one image but other images are selected together.
How can I fix it?

```
public class exAdap extends RecyclerView.Adapter<exAdap.ViewHolder>


ActionMode.Callback mActionCallback = new ActionMode.Callback(){
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu){
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode){
        mActionMode = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.pic_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_email:
                mode.finish();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

public exAdap(ArrayList<String> datas, Context context) {
    this.datas = datas;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public exAdap.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, 
  int viewType) {
    View view;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery, parent, 
false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    
 Glide.with(context).load(datas.get(position)).into(holder.getImage());
    String currentImage = datas.get(position);

    holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(multiSelect){
                selected.add(currentImage);
                holder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.check.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });

    holder.image.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            if (!multiSelect) {
                multiSelect=true;
                mActionMode = ((AppCompatActivity) 
 
 
fragment_gallery.getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(mActionCallback);
                if(selected.contains(currentImage)){
                    selected.remove(currentImage);
                }
                else{
                    selected.add(currentImage);
                    holder.check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.check.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return datas.size();
}

public void addAll(ArrayList<String> datas) {
    clearAll(false);
    this.datas = datas;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clearAll(boolean isNotify) {
    datas.clear();
    selected.clear();
    if (isNotify) notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clearSelected() {
    selected.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void selectAll() {
    selected.clear();
    selected.addAll(datas);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public ArrayList<String> getSelected() {
    return selected;
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView image;
    CheckBox check;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = itemView.findViewById((R.id.recyclerview_row_image));
        check = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkImage);

    }

    public ImageView getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }


}
```

'''

```
public class fragment_gallery extends Fragment


private ListView m_list;
private ArrayList<String> listt;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    //listt = getPic();
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new exAdap(getPic(), getContext()));
    return view;
}

public ArrayList<String> getPic() {
    ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME};

    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " desc");
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
    int columnDisplayname = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int lastIndex;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        String nameOfFile = cursor.getString(columnDisplayname);
        lastIndex = absolutePathOfImage.lastIndexOf(nameOfFile);
        lastIndex = lastIndex >= 0 ? lastIndex : nameOfFile.length() - 1;

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(absolutePathOfImage)) {
            fileList.add(absolutePathOfImage);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return fileList;
}
```

'''

Comment: error is the answer itself.. do not use getactivity in adapter use context that you passed from fragment to adapter constructor. :)

Comment: OMG... I passed activity from fragment to adapter and used 'startActionMode' and it works!! Really really thank you. But when I select pictures and scroll it, the selected pictures are changed... Do you happen to know the cause of this situation? 
Thank you so much..☺

Comment: You have to save to position of selected picture, and inside adapter, you have to check if current position is in saved list or not. If position is in saved list, then select it(change background[assuming]), else don't select.

Comment: @Unknown2433 I thought checking "selected.contains(currentImage)" or not will do that... Am I wrong?

Comment: No. You can do it in any way. You just have to save the position of selected item, which can be used later. Also remove selection if `selected.contains(currentImage)` is `false`

Comment: @Unknown2433 I added similar conditional statement right below onBindViewHolder, and it works! Thank you so much!!